# Google Drive API: 404 File not found error [custom company domain]

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, google-api, google-drive-api

I've been trying to [GET](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/reference/files/get#http-request) google drive file by file id using a service account in NodeJS, but requests are failed with the following error (meaning the [lack](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/guides/handle-errors#resolve_a_404_error_file_not_found_fileid) of access):

```
  code: 404,
  errors: [
    {
      message: 'File not found: XXX.',
      domain: 'global',
      reason: 'notFound',
      location: 'fileId',
      locationType: 'parameter'
    }
  ]
```

**Scope**

I've tried to play around with the scope by adding extra scopes, but essentially `https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive` have been always in place.

```
const scopes = [
  'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive',
  'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.appdata',
  'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.file',
  'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.metadata',
  'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.metadata.readonly',
  'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.photos.readonly',
  'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.readonly',
];
```

**Service account**

- I've created a service account, following the same conventional flow showed in different resources/docs/tutorials ([1](https://www.labnol.org/google-api-service-account-220404), [2](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/oauth2/service-account), [3](https://youtu.be/xHflVKsY9PM), etc)

[https://console.cloud.google.com/iam-admin/serviceaccounts?project=XXXX](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5NEPf.png)

- Enabled Google Drive API

[https://console.cloud.google.com/marketplace/product/google/drive.googleapis.com](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ApZdR.png)

- Enabled Domain-wide Delegation in admin google panel with the exact same scope as listed above (also had tested without additionally enabling this)

[https://admin.google.com/ac/owl/domainwidedelegation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YPbem.png)

**Source code**

There's a google nodejs [quickstart](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/quickstart/nodejs) out there for accessing drive api that works the way a user granting permissions through oauth2 modal ([example](https://www.google.com/url?sa=i&url=https%3A%2F%2Fsecurity.stackexchange.com%2Fquestions%2F193264%2Fgoogle-login-button-what-prevents-an-rogue-app-from-stealing-a-token&psig=AOvVaw2-VY2DbGhrQ4oWbWvHJIw-&ust=1671043291815000&source=images&cd=vfe&ved=0CBAQjRxqFwoTCIjJvcGf9_sCFQAAAAAdAAAAABAQ)), that's not acceptable in my case, since it must be working using service account (akka demon machine-2-machine) without any real user interaction.

I've tried out many ways:

- using [google-auth-library](https://www.npmjs.com/package/google-auth-library#impersonated-credentials-client:%7E:text=Loading%20credentials%20from%20environment%20variables) package:

```js
const { auth } = require('google-auth-library');

const client = auth.fromJSON({
  type: 'service_account',
  project_id: 'XXX',
  private_key_id: 'XXX',
  private_key: 'XXX',
  client_email: 'X@Y.iam.gserviceaccount.com',
  client_id: 'XXXX',
  auth_uri: 'https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/auth',
  token_uri: 'https://oauth2.googleapis.com/token',
  auth_provider_x509_cert_url: 'https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v1/certs',
  client_x509_cert_url:
    'https://www.googleapis.com/robot/v1/metadata/x509/X%40Y.iam.gserviceaccount.com',
});

// also tested with exact same scopes listed above
const scopes = ['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive'];
client.scopes = scopes;
// tested both options for `supportsAllDrives`: true/false

const url = `https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v3/files/XXX?fields=name&supportsAllDrives=true`;
client.request({ url }).then(console.log).catch(console.error);
```

- using [ts-google-drive](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ts-google-drive) package:

```
import { TsGoogleDrive } from 'ts-google-drive';

const tsGoogleDrive = new TsGoogleDrive({
  credentials: {
    client_email: 'X@Y.iam.gserviceaccount.com',
    private_key: '',
  },
});

async function getSingleFile(fileId: string): Promise<void> {
  // returns `undefined`, meaning an error
  const file = await tsGoogleDrive.getFile(fileId);
  console.log('file', file);
  if (file) {
    const isFolder = file.isFolder;
    console.log('isFolder', isFolder);
  }
}

getSingleFile('XXX');
```

- using [googleapis](https://www.npmjs.com/package/googleapis)

```js
const { google } = require('googleapis');

const auth = new google.auth.GoogleAuth({
  keyFile: 'service-account.json', // file properly located
  scopes: ..., // same scope
});


const drive = google.drive({ version: 'v3', auth });

const driveResponse = await drive.files.list({
fields: '*',
});

const file = await drive.files.get({
  fileId: 'XXX',
  fields: 'name',
  supportsAllDrives: true,
});

console.log(file); // error!
```

- using [googleapis](https://www.npmjs.com/package/googleapis) with jwtClient

```js
const google = require('googleapis');
const fs = require('fs');
const key = require('./service-account.json');

const scopes = ... // same

const drive = google.google.drive('v3');

const jwtClient = new google.google.auth.JWT(
  key.client_email,
  null,
  key.private_key,
  scopes,
  null,
);

jwtClient.authorize(async (authErr) => {
  if (authErr) {
    console.log(authErr); // NO error here
    return;
  }

  const drive = google.google.drive({ version: 'v3', auth: jwtClient });

  console.log('jwtClient.getCredentials()', jwtClient.getCredentials());
  console.log('jwtClient.apiKey', jwtClient.apiKey);
  console.log('jwtClient.credentials', jwtClient.credentials);
  console.log('jwtClient.gtoken', jwtClient.gtoken);

// errors occur down below when actually requesting the api
  const file = await drive.files.get({
    fileId: 'XXX',
    fields: 'name',
    supportsAllDrives: true,
  });

  console.log(file);
});
```

`./service-account` file structure:

```json
{
  "type": "service_account",
  "project_id": "X",
  "private_key_id": "XXXX",
  "client_email": "X@Y.iam.gserviceaccount.com",
  "client_id": "XXX",
  "auth_uri": "https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/auth",
  "token_uri": "https://oauth2.googleapis.com/token",
  "auth_provider_x509_cert_url": "https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v1/certs",
  "client_x509_cert_url": "https://www.googleapis.com/robot/v1/metadata/x509/X%Y.iam.gserviceaccount.com"
}
```

**Google Drive resources permissions**

Since I'm trying to access my internal company's google drive files, I'm running into issues of giving possibly required file permissions to my service account:

[attempt to share a folder/drive with my service account ended up being unsuccessful](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oO3ba.png)

It's also important to note that I've failed accessing a file that had been shared with my service account granularly (file was in "Shared with me").

Even though any **public** file in my company's drive can be accessed for no problem.

**ER**

To have it being able to access the company drive files using a service account (no real user interaction) - to highliht if it's importatn - those are located in "Shared with me" and in "Shared drives".

Comment: Are you performing impersonation for the service account? Usually when you use a service account is to impersonate a specific user from your organization so you can make the calls to the API on behalf of that user, in your examples I can't see that you are performing that thus the service account won't have access to the file unless it's shared to it.

Comment: > Are you performing impersonation for the service account

Most likely not, could you follow up with the instructions on how I can do that? Docs/resources/code snippet would so valuable!

Comment: You can find the impersonation example in the [domain wide delegation documentation](https://developers.google.com/cloud-search/docs/guides/delegation#instantiate_a_cloud_search_api_service_object) specifically check either the `Python` or `Java` code example as there it is shown how you perform impersonation of a user with the service account.

Answer (score 0):

Check the team_drive in your rclone.config file. Insert the correct id of your drive.